# Product preserving functor, natural isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Is the following true?

**Lemma.** Let $F:C \to C$ be a functor that preserves products, i.e. for all $A, B \in C$ we have isomorphism $\alpha_{A,B} : F(A\times B) \cong FA \times FB$ and this isomorphism commutes with product projections - this means $Fp_A \alpha_{A,B}=p_{FA}$.

Fix $B \in C$.

Then $\alpha_{A,B}$'s for each $A$ form a natural isomorphism:
$\alpha_{B}:F(-)\times FB \Rightarrow  F(- \times B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, whenever you have bifunctors $F,G : A\times B\to C$ and a natural transformation $\eta : F\to G$ it is easy to see that when you fix $b\in B$, $(\eta_{a,b})_{a\in A}$ is a natural transformation $F(-,b)\to G(-,b)$

Of course if $\eta$ is an isomorphism, this will be an isomorphism too

Comment: Ah, so $\alpha$ is natural iso between those bifunctors? Nice.

Comment: Well no matter the functor $F$ you have a natural morphism from $F(A\times B)$ to $FA\times FB$ defined by the universal property of the product, preserving products means that this morphism is an iso, but it is always natural